# How show results for one thing in different columns based on value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to show my query results so that the different ans_text appears in separate columns for the different ques_id.  For example, for this query,

```
SELECT
DISTINCT
p.ID
,isnull(dbo.fnRemovePatternFromString(p.Last_Name, '%[,-.'']%'), '') as [Last]
,isnull(dbo.fnRemovePatternFromString(p.First_Name, '%[,-.'']%'), '') as [First]
,isnull(dbo.fnRemovePatternFromString(p.Middle_Initial, '%[,-.'']%'), '') as [Middle]
,fs.ANS_TEXT
,fs.ques_id

FROM person p

inner JOIN person_facilities pf ON p.ID = pf.ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.ADD_ANSW fs ON p.id = fs.id and (fs.QUES_ID = 17 or fs.QUES_ID=3)

WHERE
pf.Current_status = 'Employed'
and ( fs.QUES_ID=17 or fs.QUES_ID=3)
```

The result looks like this currently:

```
ID    Last    First    Middle    ANS_TEXT   QUES_ID   
1     Veder   Darth    Boo       MFG        3
2     Mouse   Micky              MFG        3
2     Mouse   Micky              Yes        17
3     Cussler Clive              No         17
3     Cussler Clive              Non-MFG    3
4     Grafton Sue      M         Yes        17
4     Grafton Sue      M         Non-MFG    3
```

The problem is, if I revise my where clause to the following, it isn't finding the case where it's Non-MFG and Yes, which isn't correct (purpose: we need to fix it once we find it).

```
WHERE
pf.Current_status = 'Employed'
and (fs.ans_text='yes' and fs.QUES_ID=17)
and (fs.ans_text like ('Non-MFG') and fs.QUES_ID=3)
or (fs.ans_text=null and fs.QUES_ID=3)
```

How do I revise this query so I can find the cases of Non-MFG and Ques_ID=3 for a certain ID?  For the results above it would find Sue Grafton as the result.  I was thinking that maybe I can somehow change the query so the result for the initial query shows:

```
ID    Last    First    Middle    Designation Answer
4     Grafton Sue      M         Non-MFG     Yes
...
```

Then if I change the where clause to what I show above, maybe it will find Sue Grafton (Non-MFG and Yes) case in the results.  I know that I have at least 2 cases like this in my data, after looking at the first 200 or so.

Any ideas how I can get my needed results? I'm relatively new to SQL.

Comment: fs.ans_text='yes' and fs.ans_text like ('Non-MFG'), this 2 checking cannot be true together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe in your situation you need to derive multiple temp tables and then join them in final output. See if this solution works for you:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    P.ID
    ,ISNULL(DBO.FNREMOVEPATTERNFROMSTRING(P.LAST_NAME, '%[,-.'']%'), '') AS [LAST]
    ,ISNULL(DBO.FNREMOVEPATTERNFROMSTRING(P.FIRST_NAME, '%[,-.'']%'), '') AS [FIRST]
    ,ISNULL(DBO.FNREMOVEPATTERNFROMSTRING(P.MIDDLE_INITIAL, '%[,-.'']%'), '') AS [MIDDLE]
    ,FS.ANS_TEXT AS Designation
    ,FS.QUES_ID

INTO
    #TEMP1

FROM
    PERSON P

JOIN
    PERSON_FACILITIES PF
    ON P.ID = PF.ID

LEFT JOIN
    DBO.ADD_ANSW FS
    ON P.ID = FS.ID
    AND (FS.QUES_ID = 17 OR FS.QUES_ID=3)

WHERE
    PF.CURRENT_STATUS = 'EMPLOYED'
    AND (FS.QUES_ID=17 OR FS.QUES_ID=3)
    AND FS.ANS_TEXT = 'Non-MFG'
;

SELECT DISTINCT
    P.ID
    ,ISNULL(DBO.FNREMOVEPATTERNFROMSTRING(P.LAST_NAME, '%[,-.'']%'), '') AS [LAST]
    ,ISNULL(DBO.FNREMOVEPATTERNFROMSTRING(P.FIRST_NAME, '%[,-.'']%'), '') AS [FIRST]
    ,ISNULL(DBO.FNREMOVEPATTERNFROMSTRING(P.MIDDLE_INITIAL, '%[,-.'']%'), '') AS [MIDDLE]
    ,FS.ANS_TEXT AS Answer
    ,FS.QUES_ID

INTO
    #TEMP2

FROM
    PERSON P

JOIN
    PERSON_FACILITIES PF
    ON P.ID = PF.ID

LEFT JOIN
    DBO.ADD_ANSW FS
    ON P.ID = FS.ID
    AND (FS.QUES_ID = 17 OR FS.QUES_ID=3)

WHERE
    PF.CURRENT_STATUS = 'EMPLOYED'
    AND (FS.QUES_ID=17 OR FS.QUES_ID=3)
    AND FS.ANS_TEXT = 'Yes'
;

SELECT DISTINCT
    A.ID
    ,A.LAST
    ,A.FIRST
    ,A.MIDDLE
    ,A.Designation
    ,B.Answer

FROM
    #TEMP1 A

JOIN
    #TEMP2 B
    ON A.ID = B.ID
;
```

Comment: Thank you! It's working great.  Took me a while to get rid of my typos.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `UNION`

```
SELECT
DISTINCT
p.ID
,isnull(dbo.fnRemovePatternFromString(p.Last_Name, '%[,-.'']%'), '') as [Last]
,isnull(dbo.fnRemovePatternFromString(p.First_Name, '%[,-.'']%'), '') as [First]
,isnull(dbo.fnRemovePatternFromString(p.Middle_Initial, '%[,-.'']%'), '') as [Middle]
,fs.ANS_TEXT
,fs.ques_id

FROM person p

inner JOIN person_facilities pf ON p.ID = pf.ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.ADD_ANSW fs ON p.id = fs.id and (fs.QUES_ID = 17 or fs.QUES_ID=3)

WHERE
pf.Current_status = 'Employed'
and (fs.ans_text='yes' and fs.QUES_ID=17)

UNION

SELECT
DISTINCT
p.ID
,isnull(dbo.fnRemovePatternFromString(p.Last_Name, '%[,-.'']%'), '') as [Last]
,isnull(dbo.fnRemovePatternFromString(p.First_Name, '%[,-.'']%'), '') as [First]
,isnull(dbo.fnRemovePatternFromString(p.Middle_Initial, '%[,-.'']%'), '') as [Middle]
,fs.ANS_TEXT
,fs.ques_id

FROM person p

inner JOIN person_facilities pf ON p.ID = pf.ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.ADD_ANSW fs ON p.id = fs.id and (fs.QUES_ID = 17 or fs.QUES_ID=3)

WHERE
pf.Current_status = 'Employed'
and (fs.ans_text like ('Non-MFG') and fs.QUES_ID=3)

UNION

SELECT
DISTINCT
p.ID
,isnull(dbo.fnRemovePatternFromString(p.Last_Name, '%[,-.'']%'), '') as [Last]
,isnull(dbo.fnRemovePatternFromString(p.First_Name, '%[,-.'']%'), '') as [First]
,isnull(dbo.fnRemovePatternFromString(p.Middle_Initial, '%[,-.'']%'), '') as [Middle]
,fs.ANS_TEXT
,fs.ques_id

FROM person p

inner JOIN person_facilities pf ON p.ID = pf.ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.ADD_ANSW fs ON p.id = fs.id and (fs.QUES_ID = 17 or fs.QUES_ID=3)

WHERE
pf.Current_status = 'Employed'
and (fs.ans_text=null and fs.QUES_ID=3)
```

Comment: I didn't get a chance to look at this since the first one is working for me.  Thank you for responding!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for such a `WHERE` Clause

```
where pf.Current_status = 'Employed'
  and fs.ques_id in (3,17)
  and pf.id = fs.id 
  and fs.ans_text =
     ( case when fs.anx_text in ('Non-MFG','MFG','Yes') then
                  'Yes'
            when fs.anx_text in ('Non-MFG','No') then      
                  'Non-MFG'
        end )
```

to remove duplicated ID values for your query.

Comment: pf.id isn't equal to fs.ques_id.  Sorry if I made it seem like that.

Comment: No need to be sorry @Michele , excuse me, my mistake, I fixed with `pf.id = fs.id` collation.

Comment: Thanks, it's coming up with results now, but it's not showing the MFG/NON-MFG part.

Comment: @barbarousozhan - Can you get it to show mfg/non-mfg in the results too?

Comment: @Michele I just suggested to change the `WHERE` clause. If you use with this filtering condition, you'll already have only the desired `Designation` columns. Btw, I don't know about the distinction rule for `mfg vs. Non-mfg`, but of course possible by using `case..when` condition.

Comment: I couldn't get both in at the same time, but I got the other answer to work ok.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements, you're trying to find all employees who are designated 'Non-MFG', and who have 'Yes' listed as their answer to question 3.

I'd use a modified version of your initial query to just get the employees who are designated 'Non-MFG'. Since we have a filter on the table `ADD_ANSW`, that effectively makes it an inner join anyway, so I designated as such. Also, since we're filtering in the `WHERE` clause, I took the filter off the join.

From there, I added a `WHERE...EXISTS` clause to limit the results to just 'Non-MFG' employees whose question 3 answer is 'Yes'. (I always just use `SELECT 1` in an `EXISTS` query to make it clear that we're not returning any results, just confirming existence, or not, of something.)

Then, to get to your desired output, I included an in-line subquery in the `SELECT` clause to return the answer (which we already know, so it's not very exciting) to question id number 3.

```
SELECT
DISTINCT
  p.ID
  ,isnull(dbo.fnRemovePatternFromString(p.Last_Name, '%[,-.'']%'), '') as [Last]
  ,isnull(dbo.fnRemovePatternFromString(p.First_Name, '%[,-.'']%'), '') as [First]
  ,isnull(dbo.fnRemovePatternFromString(p.Middle_Initial, '%[,-.'']%'), '') as [Middle]
  ,fs.ANS_TEXT AS Designation
  ,(SELECT fs3.ANS_TEXT FROM dbo.ADD_ANSW AS fs3 WHERE fs3.QUES_ID=17 AND fs3
  .id = p.id) AS Answer
FROM 
  person p
INNER JOIN 
  person_facilities pf 
    ON p.ID = pf.ID
INNER JOIN 
  dbo.ADD_ANSW fs 
    ON p.id = fs.id 
WHERE
  pf.Current_status = 'Employed'
  AND 
  fs.QUES_ID=3
  AND 
  fs.ANS_TEXT 'Non-MFG'
  AND
  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
          FROM dbo.ADD_ANSW AS fs2 
          WHERE fs2.QUES_ID=17 AND fs2.ANS_TEXT = 'Yes' AND fs2.id = p.id);
```